# Backup form FTP to a Cloud-service

Tags: backup, cloud-service, ftp, tftp-server

Is there any software/website you can use to Backup data from an FTP server to a cloud service like Onedrive, Dropbox or google drive (or something else)?

It takes some time to download the folder to your computer and then upload it to Onedrive. Which adds an unnecessary step in between (which often also is a bottleneck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the server with FTP (usually a Linux), you can use `rsync` to synch / copy files somewhere. Question is the other cloud service, if it can be mounted to the linux machine or not.

For One drive you can use `onedrive-fuse-fs` from https://github.com/mk-fg/onedrive-fuse-fs

After One drive is sucessfully mounted to the FTP server, you can simply copy files to mounted folder by `rsync` (or if you do it only once, is enough to use `mc` - the midnight commander)

For all of this you will need some linux experience.

If the FTP server is a Windoze, then just connect One drive temporary on the server and then shre it to One drive.

If you do not have executable/admin access rights to the server, sorry...

Comment: Hmm, I'm not admin, but the webhoster offers to install things, if they are useful for everyone. I will ask them.
And thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there're many apps/services that can do the backup like CloudHQ, Cloudsfer, cBackupper... CloudHQ and Cloudsfer are like cloud-to-cloud migration and cBackupper is more relevant to what you want, the [cloud backup](https://cloud.ubackup.com) thing. Besides, cBackupper also has the PC-to-cloud backup mode, but it seems like this function has not been released yet.

Answer (score 0):

From the question it isn't really clear if the FTP server is "given" or if it's something you have the liberty to install and deploy yourself. In the latter case, you may consider to deploy your FTP (FTPS or SFTP) server directly in the cloud, which would inherently store your data in the cloud where you have deployed it.

One option is [SFTP.cloud](http://sftp.cloud), which runs on Amazon (AWS) and can be deployed in 1 click from the AWS Marketplace. This would, of course, store your data in the AWS cloud (not OneDrive or DropBox, which are more suitable for individual use as opposed to real enterprise-grade cloud services).

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using MultCloud(based on the web) to sync my OneDrive files. Since I have not used FTP before, I can’t give you an exact answer, but I do see the FTP option there, so I guess it is supported by MultCloud as well. This app is very easy to operate for me, that’s why I’m still using it.
I moved to the MultCloud page just now and found a tutorial about how to migrate files from FTP to OneDrive for you, you may have a look if you are interested. Hope it can be helpful. [Transfer Files from FTP Server to OneDrive](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/transfer-files-from-ftp-server-to-onedrive-7283.html)

Comment: Hi Gabrielle1024.  All of your answers so far recommend this single product.  Please disclose any affiliation you have with this product.  Thanks, the Software Recommendations StackExchange moderation team.